# getting reference images/videos

Tags: animation

I DO find it hard to animate with out reference videos or images.
well I am a noob at blender and I usually feel stumped and feels like writers block but for anything 3d in blender.
well can you all like help me find or create reference images and or videos.

I don't have a stand to prop my phone up on.
can yells give me some tips on getting or creative reference videos and or images please?

Comment: Are you trying to use a reference video in blender (for this site), or find reference material (for duckduckgo.com rather than this site)?

Comment: Yes i want to use it i blender, like record my self doing an action

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but https://figurosity.com has a lot of poses for reference, short animations you can find at https://www.mixamo.com, motion caption data with preview in the browser you can find here: https://mocap.web.th-koeln.de/webgl-search.php

Comment: Thanks Blunder, I guess